# Loading multiple objects in Three.js with the ObjectLoader

Tags: model, three.js, loader

I am unable to load a model in Three.js multiple times. I am trying to load a model from an array each time a button is clicked. I exported my models from Clara.io and am loading them using the ObjectLoader. I am able to load once onclick through javascript but I am not able to load another model after this by clicking the button.

HTML

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var objLoader1 = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
var models = ["../models/untitled-scene5.json", "../models/untitled-scene8.json"];


function myFunction(){
    objLoader1.load(models[Math.floor(Math.random() * models.length)],  
    function(brick){
        scene.add(brick);
    }); 
}
```

I thought that every time the button was pressed, a new model from the array would be loaded into the scene. I was able to get the functionality working correctly when I made my own mesh using THREE.BoxGeometry. I had a function that deleted the previous geometry and then loaded a new one from an array.

I have been stuck for three days and would really appreciate some help. Thanks,
Steven

Comment: Can you share your code somewhere where it runs?  I can check it out.